# Let $V$ be an inner product space. Show that if $||x+y||=||x||+||y||$, then $ax=by$ where $a,b$ are non-negative and not both zero.

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, inner-products

Let $V$ be an inner product space. Show that if $||x+y||=||x||+||y||$, then $ax=by$ where $a,b$ are non-negative and not both zero.

I know that the converse is true. I considered the square of the norm sum.

$||x+y||^2=(||x||+||y||)^2=||x||^2+2||x||||y||+||y||^2$

I'm not sure how to conclude that $ax=by$ any hints or solutions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just let $y=u+v$ where $v\cdot x=0$.

Comment: Are you working on a **real** inner product? I ask because of the conditions on $\;a,b\;$

Comment: It doesn't specify.

Comment: @Timbuc I don't think that the result depends on the real or complex case. In both cases the hypothesis $\Vert x+y\Vert = \Vert x \Vert + \Vert y \Vert$ implies the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Use the equality case of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and the fact that in your case the scalar product of $x$ and $y$ is positive.